# remove upload button from toolbar

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

I have integrated ckeditor with ckfinder. I want to remove the upload button from tool bar. When u click images/links from ckeditor, a file browser opens and then click "browse server" button. It opens another browser when you can browse the folders. On the top there is a tool bar section where we can find "Settings, Help and upload" buttons. I have to remove that upload button. i am using javascript. Please help

Comment: i did google for this and i did not find any answer to do this

Comment: Ahh, it's not the CKEditor toolbar directly. I see.

Comment: Write the your Own toolbar in Ckeditor.js without Id of the Upload in that toolbar.See this http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Toolbar_Customization

Answer (score 0):

For removing ckfinder upload button then you need to add some code in ckfinder config.js

```
CKFinder.config.toolbar_Full = [['Refresh', 'Settings', 'Maximize']];
```

hope it is works

Answer (score 0):

Set on main config.js (ckfinder 3 root folder):

```
config.removeModules = 'UploadFileButton';
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this way of customizing toolbars

```
editor_edit = CKEDITOR.replace( 'e_notification', {
uiColor: '#888888',
height: '250px',
filebrowserBrowseUrl : 'http://localhost/SUServer1/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : 'http://localhost/SUServer1/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl : 'http://localhost/SUServer1/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash',
filebrowserUploadUrl : 'http://localhost/SUServer1/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
filebrowserImageUploadUrl : 'http://localhost/SUServer1/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : 'http://localhost/SUServer1/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash',
filebrowserWindowWidth : '1000',
filebrowserWindowHeight : '700',
toolbar :
[
    { name: 'document', items : [ 'Source','-','Templates' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv',
    '-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ] },
    { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','Iframe' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] }
]
});
```